# spring boot does not read property values from application.properties file when run on command line but works when application is run from Intellij

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I have a multimodule maven spring-boot application and I have defined different properties file for different deployment environments.

Following is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>be.custom.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>custom-maven-pom</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.3</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>myapp</artifactId>
    <groupId>be.custom.myapp</groupId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>My Application</name>
    <description>Backend application for myapp</description>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven.shade.plugin>3.2.3</maven.shade.plugin>
        <lib.spring-boot.version>2.1.17.RELEASE</lib.spring-boot.version>
        <lib.spring-boot-thin-layout.version>1.0.24.RELEASE
        </lib.spring-boot-thin-layout.version>
        <version.spring-cloud-netflix-zuul>2.1.6.RELEASE</version.spring-cloud-netflix-zuul>
        <lombok.version>1.18.16</lombok.version>
        <mapstruct.version>1.3.1.Final</mapstruct.version>
        <required.codecoverage>0.0</required.codecoverage>
        <start-class>be.custom.myapp.WebApplication</start-class>
        <lib.swagger.annotations.version>1.5.13
        </lib.swagger.annotations.version>
        <lib.springfox.swagger.version>2.9.2</lib.springfox.swagger.version>
        <openapi.version>0.2.1</openapi.version>
        <cxf.version>3.4.4</cxf.version>
        <sonar.projectName>myfleet-api</sonar.projectName>
        <sonar.java.coveragePlugin>jacoco</sonar.java.coveragePlugin>
        <sonar.dynamicAnalysis>reuseReports</sonar.dynamicAnalysis>
        <sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths>${project.basedir}/target/site/jacoco/jacoco.xml</sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths>
        <sonar.language>java</sonar.language>
        <owasp.CVSSv3.threshold>10</owasp.CVSSv3.threshold>
        <owasp.skip>true</owasp.skip>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>${lib.spring-boot.version}</version>
            <!--<exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                &lt;!&ndash;<exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>&ndash;&gt;
            </exclusions>-->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws.serverless</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-serverless-java-container-springboot2</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <version>${lib.spring-boot.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <!--<exclusions>
                &lt;!&ndash;<exclusion>
                    <groupId>junit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                </exclusion>&ndash;&gt;
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>-->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>${lib.spring-boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ojdbc6</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
            <version>12.1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct-jdk8</artifactId>
            <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.10.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.bucket4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>bucket4j_jdk8-core</artifactId>
            <version>8.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>be.custom.myapp</groupId>
                <artifactId>myapp-standalone</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>be.custom.myapp</groupId>
                <artifactId>myapp-api</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>be.custom.myapp</groupId>
                <artifactId>myapp-facade</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>be.custom.myapp</groupId>
                <artifactId>myapp-management</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>be.custom.myapp</groupId>
                <artifactId>myapp-model</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>be.custom.myapp</groupId>
                <artifactId>myapp-restadapter</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- Open Api and Swagger -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
                <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
                <version>${lib.swagger.annotations.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
                <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
                <version>${lib.springfox.swagger.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
                <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
                <version>${lib.springfox.swagger.version}</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-databind-nullable</artifactId>
                <version>${openapi.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
                <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
                <version>2.9.9</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- CXF -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-spring-boot-starter-jaxws</artifactId>
                <version>${cxf.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-rt-features-logging</artifactId>
                <version>${cxf.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
                <version>${cxf.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-rt-bindings-soap</artifactId>
                <version>${cxf.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
                <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
                <version>2.21.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-rt-ws-security</artifactId>
                <version>${cxf.version}</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
                        <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>be.axa.comrm</groupId>
                <artifactId>common-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.0.2</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
                        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>  <!-- declare the exclusion here -->
                        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>

    </dependencyManagement>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>local</id>
            <properties>
                <activatedProperties>local</activatedProperties>
            </properties>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>dev</id>
            <properties>
                <activatedProperties>dev</activatedProperties>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>preprod</id>
            <properties>
                <activatedProperties>preprod</activatedProperties>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>prod</id>
            <properties>
                <activatedProperties>prod</activatedProperties>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${lib.spring-boot.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <profiles>
                        <profile>local</profile>
                        <profile>dev</profile>
                        <profile>preprod</profile>
                        <profile>prod</profile>
                    </profiles>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot.experimental</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-thin-layout</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0.24.RELEASE</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-help-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>show-profiles</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>active-profiles</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.shade.plugin}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <manifestEntries>
                                        <Main-Class>${start-class}</Main-Class>
                                        <Start-Class>${start-class}</Start-Class>
                                    </manifestEntries>
                                </transformer>
                                <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                    <resource>META-INF/cxf/bus-extensions.txt</resource>
                                </transformer>
                                <transformer
                                        implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                    <resource>META-INF/spring.factories</resource>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                            <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
                            <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok-mapstruct-binding</artifactId>
                            <version>0.2.0</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.properties</include>
                    <include>**/*.json</include>
                </includes>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.jks</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>
    <modules>
        <module>myapp-standalone</module>
        <module>myapp-api</module>
        <module>myapp-model</module>
        <module>myapp-facade</module>
        <module>myapp-management</module>
        <module>myapp-restadapter</module>
    </modules>
</project>
```

I have defined a property `custom.property=Some Environment specific Value` inside all the `application.properties` file

Following are my application.properties file

```
application.properties
application-local.properties
application-dev.properties
```

Inside application.properties file I have set only one property which is as follows

```
spring.profiles.active=@activatedProperties@
```

The property `custom.property=Some Environment Specific Value` is defined inside remaining .properties files which are `application-local.properties` and `application-dev.properties`

I have created a controller which is as follows

```
@RestController
public class TestController {

    @Value("${custom.property}")
    private String activeProfile;

    @GetMapping("/testing")
    public ResponseEntity<String> getTestMEthod() {

        String message = activeProfile + "says hello";
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(message);
    }
```

Now when I run my application from intellij, the application starts alright and the controller also sends an appropriate response by picking values from .properties file

but when I run my application from command line using following command

`java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=local target\myapp-standalone-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar`

The application doesn't start at all and instead I get the following error

```
15:02:49.234 [main] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'testController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'custom.property' in value "${custom.property}"
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:382)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1402)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:591)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:514)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:319)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:866)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:744)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:391)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1204)
        at be.axa.pccorporate.myfleet.WebApplication.main(WebApplication.java:13)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'custom.property' in value "${custom.property}"
        at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:178)
        at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:124)
        at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.doResolvePlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:239)
        at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.resolveRequiredPlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:210)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.lambda$processProperties$0(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:175)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveEmbeddedValue(AbstractBeanFactory.java:857)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1217)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1196)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:595)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:376)
        ... 17 common frames omitted
```

Not sure what's going wrong.

Comment: the problem is most likely that application.properties can't be found (I assume it's under /resources). If I remember correctly, I simply copied application.properties to the folder with the runnable jar file. This file needs to be outside the jar file anyway so that users can modify it at any time,

Answer (score 0):

*Have you added custom.property to the application.properties file?*

Comment: No,it's not that, since the property is found when run from within the IDE.

Comment: yes. i've added custom.property in application.properties

Comment: you try to use
'mvn clean install'

'java -jar Dcustom.property=abcd app.jar'

Let's try